# Vega Lite (v4) - What transform do I use for this?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, airtable, vega-lite-api

I am trying to create a graph that displays the count of appearances of different keywords per month (to find out which keywords are in 'popular season').

Currently, I am attempting to display a single keyword as an area, with a dotted line of "total" records overlaid so we can see the "relative" volume of keyword appearances.

Picture of my graph

[image: 1]

My issue is I've accomplished this one way, but I'd like to figure out transforms to do it better as I keep creating this view.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": "Kingstree Plumbing Calls by Keyword",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "transform": [ 
      {"filter" : "datum['Call type'] !== 'Non-Client'"},
      {
        
        "calculate" : "indexof(lower(datum['Call Reason'] === null ? '' : datum['Call Reason']), 'sump') !== -1 ? 'Sump' : 'Total'", "as": "filtered"

      },
      {
        "calculate" : "month(datum['Time Created'])", "as": "rawMonth"
      },
      {
        "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "calls"}],
        "groupby": ["rawMonth", "filtered"]
      },
      {
        "impute": "calls",
        "key": "rawMonth",
        "groupby" : ["filtered"], 
        "method" : "value",
        "value": 0,
        "keyvals": {"start": 0, "stop": 12}
    },
    
    {"calculate" : "datetime(2022, datum.rawMonth)", "as": "newMonth"}
    
    ],
  

"encoding" : {
  
   "x": {
        "timeUnit" :"month",
        "field" : "newMonth",
        "type": "temporal",
        "title": ""
    },
    "y": {
      "field" : "calls",
      "type": "quantitative",
        "axis": {
            "tickMinStep": 1,
            "tickCount" : 10
          },
      "title" : "Call Volume"
    }
},
 "layer" : [{
  "transform"  : [{"filter" : "datum.filtered === 'Sump'"}],
  "layer" : [
    {
      "mark" : {
        "type" : "area",
        "interpolate" : "monotone",
        "line" : true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark" : {
        "type" : "circle"
      }
    }
  ]},
  {
    "transform"  : [{"filter" : "datum.filtered === 'Total'"}],
    "mark" : {
      "type": "line",
      "interpolate" :"monotone",
      "strokeDash": [
          10,
          15
        ],
        "color" : "#aaaaaa"
    }
  }]
}
```

In the code above, I've created a table of records that contain the volume "calls" of keyword appearances for 1 source, flagging each record with its source. I then use a filter per layer to display one flag each.
For example my data *should* have been transformed to look like this:

| Month | calls | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| april | 12 | total |
| april | 4 | keyword1 |
| may | 25 | total |
| may | 3 | keyword1 |

But what I would instead want is a table that looks like this

| Month | total | keyword1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| april | 12 | 4 |
| may | 25 | 3 |

From what I am reading, this could be accomplished by perhaps a stack or fold transform but I am having trouble understanding how I might use them correctly.

As a note, the impute and rawMonth stuff is just my solution to the aggregation creating null values instead of zero, it's turning the date into a number and using that to impute the missing one, and then turning it BACK into a date (as I do not know how to impute date fields)

(also I am using v4 because airtable)

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention the reason for this is so I can calculate extra fields per month like "keyword1 / total" which (to my knowledge) would be exceedingly more difficult with the *flagged records* table layout I have now

Comment: If this is a transform question, can you supply sample input and expected output. The spec doesn't have any data so it is impossible to know without a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your example table 1 to table 2, try ***pivot*** transform.

[Vega-lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/pivot.html):

```
{
  "pivot": "keyword",
  "groupby": ["Month"],
  "value": "calls"
}
```

[Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/pivot/):

```
{
  "type": "pivot",
  "groupby": ["Month"],
  "field": "keyword",
  "value": "calls"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like exactly what I am trying to do!

However, whenever I use pivot it throws an error like it isn't creating the fields. I've made another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325299/vega-lite-v4-pivot-example-and-my-code-throwing-errors

Comment: Current version of Vega-lite (v5.2.0) pivot transform works with no errors. See example at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325299/vega-lite-v4-pivot-example-and-my-code-throwing-errors/73326518#73326518